# Entity Framework errors when when eager loading multiple navigation properties

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, .net-4.5

I'm trying to include multiple linq expressions for eager loading nav properties. I have found many many blogs/tutorials,S.O. Questions covering the topic, however upon implementation none seem to work. The strangest thing is that if I litterally implement the include on the query it does work, but that of course defeats the purpose of passing numerous amounts of expressions. Let me show you an example.
COntroller repo call:

```
// GET api/application/5
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
        {
            var _repo = new BaseRepository();
            
            //_repo.Find<Application>(a => a.Id == id).Result
            var app = Task.Run(async () => { return await _repo.Find<Application>(id,
                                                         e => e.Users); 
                                           }
                              ).Result;
            if (app != null)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, app);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound,
                                   "The application could not be located.");
            }
            
        }
```

Repo Method with varying ways of including the parameters:

```
public async Task<T> Find<T>(int id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes) 
        where T: Application
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = _db.Set<T>();

            //for (var i = 0; i < includes.Length; i++)
            //    query = query.Include(includes[i]);

            //foreach (var include in includes)
            //{
            //    query = query.Include<T, object>(include);
            //}

            //if (includes.Any())
            //{
            //    query = includes.Aggregate<Expression<Func<T, object>>, IQueryable<T>>
            //            (_db.Set<T>(), (current, expression) => current.Include(expression));
            //return await query.Where(e => e.Id == id).AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefaultAsync();    
            //}

            return await query.Where(e => e.Id == id).SingleOrDefaultAsync();       
        }
```

The only way that doesn't throw an error:

```
return await query.Include(includes[0]).Where(e => e.Id == id).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

The Error:

> {Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation}
>
> Inner Exception:
> {Duplicate Type Name Within Assembly}

I'm really hitting a wall on this one with what I understand this should work just swimmingly on any these looped implementations. And yet on execution of the query it throws an error.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Looks like http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2228

Comment: Interesting.. It's true when I stopped debugging it did work. How very strange that this would be the case.

Comment: Not really if you look at the comments in the bug - the fix just went in. I believe that VS is killing a thread that started doing proxy generation (possibly due to a time-out) and this causes an issue EF is trying generating proxies again using a ModelBuilder that had some leftovers from the first run.

Comment: I am using the latest version of entity framework. What exactly are you proposing as a solution.

Comment: The fix should be in a nightly build (probably tomorrow?) and as you can see in the bug is assigned to the 6.1.1 release.